# Optimal way to solve querying (redundant) data

Tags: javascript, database, graphql

I have a dilemma on how to solve possible redundant data querying.

I am using MongoDB with Apollo server and client. My MongoDB has several collections of data. The main collection consists of IDs pointing to supporting collections.

I am not sure about how to solve the mapping of IDs of my main collection to supporting collections IDs to retrieve the actual values. The thing is that mostly I already have data of supporting collections cached in Apollo client cache.

Do you think I should only query the IDs in my main collection and map IDs to values on the frontend using cached data? Or should I have a resolver that takes IDs in main collection, makes database queries to supporting collections to get value for each ID and then sends prepared data to frontend?

I appreciate any insight! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As always, it depends. I assume that this is your setup, with a *main collection*.

```
type OtherDoc {
  id: String
  field: String
}

type MainDoc {
  id: String
  otherDocs(param: String): [OtherDoc]
}

type Query {
  mainDocs: [MainDoc]
}
```

In such case, querying for `mainDocs { id otherDocs("...") { id field } }` is definitely a natural way to get this data. It *might* be redundant, in terms of getting `OtherDoc` when different `param` result in the same docs. If so, you *may* think about querying only their IDs and then querying for separate docs, if the client doesn't have them.

I'd say it's a valid solution, but definitely not something you should consider from the beginning. This optimization will definitely limit the bandwidth, but increase the number of requests. What is more, you don't know when to actually refetch `OtherDoc`. Well, maybe you do, but you have to think about and build it, where without you have it out-of-the-box.

A different approach, a more cache-friendly one, may change the schema to limit such situations, where your data overlap. This is not always possible due to the business logic, but worth considering if it is.